# using form input in different pages and handling actions dynamically

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have four files, they are `index.php`, `commonform.php`, `image1.php`, `image2.php`

Suppose, in the `index.php` I have a form with two image input, the form's `action` change dynamically, `method` is `post`. when the first image is clicked is goes to `commonform.php` and also when the second image is clicked is goes to `commonform.php` but in commonform I have a form with some button input (its work can be anything and not my concern) and a submit button. My concern is when the first image is clicked, it goes to `commonform.php` and when the submit button is clicked of `commonform.php`, it goes to `image1.php` and same things for when the second image is clicked, it goes to `commonform.php` and when the submit button is clicked of `commonform.php`, it goes to `image2.ph`p. Can anyone help me?

Comment: what do you mean by "two image input" do you mean file uploads?

Comment: What do you mean by "when the first image is clicked is goes to `commonform.php` " . Do you mean the page redirects?

Comment: <input type="image" name="iamge1" src="/image/" >
<br><br>
<input type="image" name="iamge2" src="/image/" >
<br><br>

Comment: and yes the page redirects

Comment: What is the problem youre having? I dont understand what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

You may attach a variable to your requests in `index.php` and then recognize it in `commonform.php` and decide to jump to the target destination !

For Example :

index.php

```
<form action="commonform.php" method="POST">
  <input type="image" name="image_1" src="image1.gif" alt="Image 1">
  <input type="image" name="image_2" src="image2.gif" alt="Image 2">
</form>
```

commonform.php

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['image_1_x'], $_POST['image_1_y'])) {
    $action = 'image1.php'; 
} 
if (isset($_POST['image_2_x'], $_POST['image_2_y'])) {
    $action = 'image2.php'; 
} 

?>

<form id="commonform" action="<?php echo $action; ?>" method="POST">
    <input type="button" value="From HTML">
    <input type="button" value="Content">
    <input type="button" value="Button style ">
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

when you are processing the INPUT with IMAGE type artibute ; it sends the X , Y artibutes , we just need to check them !

Comment: but in commonform.php  I have a form with some button input (its work can be anything and not my concern) and a submit button. and when submit button is clicked it should remember which image was clicked and go to corresponding php files

Comment: in this case you may first set session for incoming image and then take the control at the last point.
If you provide your code sample we may help more better ...

Comment: index.php
<form action="commonform.php" method="POST">
  <input type="image" name="image_1" src="image1.gif" alt="Image 1">
  <input type="image" name="image_2" src="image2.gif" alt="Image 2">
</form>

Commonform.php
<form id="commonform" 
action="###this is my concern.it want when image1 is clicked it action goes to image1.php and for 2nd image it goes to image2.php####" 
method="POST"> 
<input type="button" value="From HTML">
<input type="button" value="Content">
<input type="button" value="Button style ">
<br><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value=" “
</form>

Comment: Use this code for file `commonform.php` ...
`
<?php
if (isset($_POST['image_1'])) {
  $action = 'image1.php';
}
if (isset($_POST['image_2'])) {
  $action = 'image2.php';
}
?>

<form id="commonform" action="<?php echo $action; ?>" method="POST">
  <input type="button" value="From HTML">
  <input type="button" value="Content">
  <input type="button" value="Button style ">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
`

Comment: that is what i am talking about and you understand correctly. but unfortunately action="<?php echo $action; ?>" is not working. i don't know why. please have a look.

Comment: I'll send you the final result by editing my answer !

Comment: thanks man.it's working. sorry i am not able to give u a upvote because of my insufficient reputation

Comment: Happy to hear that ! So approve the answer to make it easy for orhers to find the solution.